# WooCommerce Product page Hide div if product is in-stock

Tags: php, woocommerce, show-hide

I need help with php coding to functions.php.
I have a woocommerce shop, and I have products in-stock, and products out of stock or on-backorder.
I'm using TM extra product options to show shipping options(div name: tc-row), and I need this:
If product is in-stock -> hide tc-row in product page.
If product out of stock or backorder -> show tc-row in product page.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Pneu

I'm trying to made php code, but I can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with CSS depending on where the TM Extra Product Options plugin is placing their HTML. The product will have a class of "outofstock" or something like that. Sometimes the theme will mess with that, but check the classes on your product container on the product page. So if the TM stuff is inside that container (or even a sibling) you can use that as your css:

```
.outofstock .tmstuff .tc-row {
    display:block;
}
```

or

```
div:not(.outofstock) .tmstuff .tc-row {
    display:none;
}
```